# Make sibling class disappear on click with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, siblings

Hello again community,

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="containertira">
     <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="img/Tiras/1 - Minho.png">
     <div class="centered"> Minho</div>
</div>
```

And I have a JS in which when I click on a `.imgclasstosize` it changes it to `img.imgclasstosize.big` while reverting any previsous changed `img.imgclasstosize.big` to `img.imgclasstosize`.

Here it is:

```
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.imgclasstosize');
allImages.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
    const thisImg = event.target;
    const allOtherImages = Array.from(allImages).filter(img => {
       return img !== thisImg;
    });
  
    allOtherImages.forEach(img => {
        img.classList.remove('big')
    });
  
    thisImg.classList.toggle('big');
  
  });
});
```

My question is: Is it possible when clicking the `.imgclasstosize` to also make disappear its sibling class `.centered`, and also revert it back to visible when `img.imgclasstosize.big` goes back to  `.imgclasstosize`?

Second part of the question is: Whatever content I throw inside the div "centered" is blocking the click and the subsequent action, mainly in my case because I'm using text above an image. So if for instance, I click on the text inside `.centered` that is positioned above the img inside `.imgclasstosize`, no action happens. How can I make it assume that clicking on `.imgclasstosize` and on `.centered` is the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) to toggle the classes and you can hide them using CSS. I have added additional codes and comments for your requirement.

```js
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.imgclasstosize');
allImages.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const thisImg = event.target;
      const sibling = thisImg.nextElementSibling; // Get the next sibling
      sibling.classList.toggle("hide"); // Add class to the current sibling

      const allOtherImages = Array.from(allImages).filter(img => {
        return img !== thisImg;
      });
      allOtherImages.forEach(img => {
        img.classList.remove('big');
        const otherSiblings = img.nextElementSibling;
        otherSiblings.classList.remove("hide"); // Remove hide class from other image siblings
      });
      thisImg.classList.toggle('big');


    });
  }

);
```

```css
.containertira {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.imgclasstosize {
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.imgclasstosize.big {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.centered {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.imgclasstosize.big+.centered.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="containertira">
  <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="centered"> First image</div>
  <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="centered"> Second image</div>
  <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="centered"> Third image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This did precisely what I needed. Thank you so much for your knowledge. One behaviour that is happening though is that whatever content I throw inside the div "centered"  is blocking the click and the action, mainly in my case because i'm using text above an image.

Comment: Please update the question or open a new question with the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Updated. Sorry friend.

Comment: No problem, I see you have updated the question but there was never a question that the image or text was positioned with CSS or something. In order not to have a mixup, please open a new question with the code edited with your text on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling` property to refer to the sibling node.

You can read more about this here:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp